# SQL; How to write "Order By" statement that it will switch up whenever it found the first match

Tags: mysql, case, sql-order-by

I apologize if this question have been made before.

This is my original table.

| user_name | Usertype | Team |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Benjamin Turner | Support | Cat Welfare Society |
| Luis Bennett | Main | Cat Welfare Society |
| Benjamin Turner | Support | Andal Youths |
| Benjamin Turner | Support | ACaretalyst |
| Cynthia Bender | Main | Volunteer Centre |
| Benjamin Turner | Support | Volunteer Centre |

I want to rearrange this using Order by, so that Main account will appear first, follow by the Support account of the same team. Those other teams that Benjamin support but there is no Main account, will be added in at the bottom.

"EXPECTED RESULT"

| user_name | Usertype | Team |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Luis Bennett | Main | Cat Welfare Society |
| Benjamin Turner | Support | Cat Welfare Society |
| Cynthia Bender | Main | Volunteer Centre |
| Benjamin Turner | Support | Volunteer Centre |
| Benjamin Turner | Support | Andal Youths |
| Benjamin Turner | Support | ACaretalyst |

I have tried
"Order by usertype , team"  which results in listing for all the Main account first ,THEN support account (meaning Main and Support of the same team do not stick together)

| user_name | Usertype | Team |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Luis Bennett | Main | Cat Welfare Society |
| Cynthia Bender | Main | Volunteer Centre |
| Benjamin Turner | Support | Cat Welfare Society |
| Benjamin Turner | Support | Volunteer Centre |
| Benjamin Turner | Support | Andal Youths |
| Benjamin Turner | Support | ACaretalyst |

On other hands, if I tried "Order by team, usertype"  then Main account and Support account stick together, but the team without any Main , will then appear first ( due alphabetical order)

| user_name | Usertype | Team |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Benjamin Turner | Support | ACaretalyst |
| Benjamin Turner | Support | Andal Youths |
| Luis Bennett | Main | Cat Welfare Society |
| Benjamin Turner | Support | Cat Welfare Society |
| Cynthia Bender | Main | Volunteer Centre |
| Benjamin Turner | Support | Volunteer Centre |

Is there any way to structure the order by so that the first row is always the Main Account first, then follow by related Support of the same team ( regardless of the alphabetical order of the Team)
Then whatever remaining Support accounts (without any Main account) will be added in bottom

Comment: What version of MySQL? v5.x and v8+ have very different functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we want to sort according by these rules

- Complete `Team`s (which has a user with `Main` `UserType`) first
- Then by `Team` (to ensure `Main` and `Support` go together)
- Finally, within each `Team` sort by `UserType`: `Main`, `Support` and all the rest

We can try doing it as

```
with MyUsers as (
  select user_name,
         Usertype,
         Team,
         case 
           when exists (select 1 
                          from MyTable m 
                         where m.Team = Team 
                           and m.Usertype = 'Main') then 1
           else 2
         end CompleteGroupOrder,     
         case 
           when Usertype = 'Main' then 1
           when Usertype = 'Support' then 2
           else 3
         end TeamOrder
    from MyTable)

  select user_name,
         Usertype,
         Team
    from MyUsers
order by CompleteGroupOrder,
         Team, 
         TeamOrder
```

Comment: Oh thank you so much. While your query did not work on mine but you gave me the idea of adding another column to do the ranking as per condition separately.